# Python code to create mirror of an image and blend it with certain amount of white color.

Tags: python, colors, flip

I'm a very newbie to Python and i'm trying to learn manipulating pictures with Python. This piece of code below is to create a mirror image of a picture and then fade it to white. But i got bellow error when i execute the code "The error was: 'int' and 'function'
Inappropriate argument type.
An attempt was made to call a function with a parameter of an invalid type. This means that you did something such as trying to pass a string to a method that is expecting an integer." I'm not sure what causes this error and i need help with this.

```
def blendWhite(pixcel, fadeAmount):
    newRed = 255 * fadeAmount + getRed(pixel) * (1 - fadeAmount)
    newGreen = 255 * fadeAmount + getGreen(pixel) * (1 - fadeAmount)
    newBlue = 255 * fadeAmount + getBlue(pixel) * (1 - fadeAmount)
    setColor(pixel, makeColor(newRed, newGreen, newBlue))

def copyAndMirrorCat():
    catFile = getMediaPath("caterpillarSmall.jpg")
    catPict = makePicture(catFile)
    width = getWidth(catPict)
    height = getHeight(catPict)
    canvas = makeEmptyPicture(width, height * 2)
    # Now, do the actual copying
    for x in range(0, width):
        for y in range(0, height):
            color = getColor(getPixel(catPict, x, y))
            setColor(getPixel(canvas, x, y), color)
            h = height * 2
            fadeAmount(y, h)
            blendWhite(getPixel(canvas, x, (height * 2) - y - 1), fadeAmount)
    show(catPict)
    show(canvas)
    return canvas

def fadeAmount(y, h):
    fm = (h - y) / float(h) + 0.15
    if fm > 1:
        fm = 1
    return fm
```

This is how result looks like: http://imageshack.us/a/img442/326/mirrorlinearwithwhite.jpg

Comment: You should share more of your error.  If you read through it, you'll see a line number in there so you can tell where it came from.  Context is important.  Including what libraries you're using is helpful as well.

I suspect that you have a problem has something to do with "fadeAmount" - you call the function without saving the value & then try passing the function name to blendWhite().

Comment: the error happens at line
newRed = 255*fadeAmount + getRed(pixel)*(1-fadeAmount)

Comment: Typo in the first line, `pixcel`.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the lines where you say:

```
fadeAmount(y,h) 
blendWhite(getPixel(canvas,x,(height*2)-y-1),fadeAmount)
```

You'll see that you call `fadeAmount()` without storing the value in a variable.  You then try to pass the function to `blendWhite()`.  This just won't work.  You need to either store the value and pass it, like :

```
fa = fadeAmount(y,h)
blendWhite(getPixel(canvas,x,(height*2)-y-1),fa)
```

...or just make it all one statement:

```
blendWhite(getPixel(canvas,x,(height*2)-y-1),fadeAmount(y,h))
```

Comment: Thanks. I fix that. It runs but the mirror image doesn't show up, there's only a plain white section under original image.

Comment: @banff well, Now you're left with logic problems rather than exploding programs.  Back to work.